# What are the factors affecting the ability to enable/disable VoLTE?

Tags: android-10, android-11, samsung-galaxy-s-9, voice-over-lte, samsung-galaxy-a20

In response to this [zero-day vulnerabilities for certain Exynos chipsets](https://9to5google.com/2023/03/16/google-exynos-modem-vulnerabilities/), I tried to turn off VoLTE on Samsung Galaxy S9 running Android 10 (build number QP1A.190711.020.G960USQU9FVB2) but couldn't find the setting under Connections -> Mobile Networks.  This phone runs on the USA AT&T network.  (Thanks for the tip that G960U doesn't use Exynos; even in G960F which does use it, the model is not affected.)

But I did find the setting to turn it off in another Samsung Galaxy phone, an A20 running Android 11 that runs on the BoostMobile network (which I believe uses the AT&T network as an MVNO).  Again, although this phone [does use Exynos 7884](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_a20-9640.php) it may not be vulnerable, going by the [list of chipsets provided by Samsung](https://semiconductor.samsung.com/support/quality-support/product-security-updates/).

**My question**: What are the factors affecting the ability to enable/disable VoLTE?  Is it based on the OS version, the chipset, the provider, or the location (dynamically, based on the presence of LTE there)?  It seems that [for some MVNOs it cannot be turned off](https://www.androidcentral.com/volte)?

Another way to pose the question is in terms of technology.  In areas where 4G is the only network (since [both AT&T and Verizon would have turned off their 2G and 3G networks by now](https://www.fcc.gov/consumers/guides/plan-ahead-phase-out-3g-cellular-networks-and-service)), **do ALL voice calls over 4G network are necessarily voice over IP**?  If not, does turning off VoLTE means simply that you cannot use data while making calls?

Comment: Perhaps related on [Android Central](https://www.androidcentral.com/how-enable-volte-samsung-galaxy-s9): "*My carrier (Jio) primarily uses VoLTE for calls, so there's no option to turn it off, but you should be able to see a toggle to enable or disable the feature. You'll also see different options on the Mobile networks menu depending on your S9 or S9+ model (I'm using the Exynos-based SM-G965F).*" That said, Galaxy S9 doesn't seem to be affected by the vulnerability?

Comment: Also on [Indonesian Samsung Support](https://r1.community.samsung.com/t5/galaxy-s/s9-menu-volte-nya-tidak-muncul/m-p/9179366/highlight/true#M76320): "*OK, I know the problem. When I put the "Telkomsel" SIM card, the menu was shown. That means the setting depends on the SIM card and its provider. Seems the "Indosat" network is the problem*"

Comment: Does AT&T still provide an 2G and/or 3G network? If there is no 2G and 3G network then VoLTE is the only way to perform voice calls.

Comment: According to gmsarena the [G960U](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s9-8966.php#g960u) doesn't use Exynos chipset, instead it uses an Qualcomm SDM845 Snapdragon 845. So you should not be affected.

Comment: @Robert Thanks.  I have updated the question to more general and more interesting.  Yes, it appears AT&T [shut off its 2G in 2017](https://www.fiercewireless.com/wireless/at-t-confirms-it-shut-down-its-2g-network-jan-1) and [started shutting lff its 3G in 2022](https://www.fcc.gov/consumers/guides/plan-ahead-phase-out-3g-cellular-networks-and-service).  Do you mean that in areas where there is no 2G and 3G networks, VoLTE is the only way to perform voice calls; that there is no "voice-only" mode?

Comment: Starting with 4G there is no voice mode anymore, only VoIP modes like VoLTE. That simplifies the overall network layout and also the network provider prefer nowadays the all-over-IP approach.

Comment: @Robert So per vulnerability mitigation, turning off VoLTE and Voice over Wifi will effectively eliminate the ability to make phone calls in areas where there is only 4G but no 2G and 3G?  I'm confused.